# Blazor WASM - There was an error trying to log you in: 'this._settings.loginMode is undefined'

Tags: azure-web-app-service, blazor, blazor-webassembly, azure-ad-msal, hosted-blazor-webassembly

I've created a new dotnet 6 blazor wasm app with the core hosted option. The Visual Studio 2022 (v17.3.1) template creates Client, Server and Shared projects for this.

I've updated the Server project's program.cs to make use of Azure ADB2C as follows:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C"));
```

Its appsettings.json contains the following:

"AzureAdB2C": {
"Instance": "https://mydomain.b2clogin.com/",
"ClientId": "serverprojclientidhere",
"Domain": "mydomain.onmicrosoft.com",
"Scopes": "access_as_user",
"SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_SignUpIn"
}

In the client project, the program.cs contains the following:

```
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
    options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("https://mydomain.onmicrosoft.com/api/Api.ReadWrite");
});
```

Its appsettings.json contains the following:

```
"AzureAdB2C": {
    "Authority": "https://mydomain.b2clogin.com/mydomain.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SignUpIn",
    "ClientId": "clientprojclientidhere",
    "ValidateAuthority": false
  }
```

When I run this locally it works fine. The website loads and presents the home screen, if I select a "secured" page then I'm redirected to the ADB2C.

I have a devops pipeline that's deployed the solution to an Azure App Service (linux). If I go to the site it presents the hope page ok but on navigating to a secured page I get the following error message:

> There was an error trying to log you in: 'this._settings.loginMode is
> undefined'

I don't see any errors in the browser's console window.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I managed to find the answer from this [blog post](https://www.koskila.net/fixing-blazor-webassembly-net-6-msal-authorization-bug/)

Resolution was to add the following to the client project's csproj file:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <TrimmerRootAssembly Include="Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal" />
  </ItemGroup>
```