# Blazor WASM error: 'window.crypto.randomUUID is not a function'

Tags: blazor, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

When I deploy my asp.net Blazor WASM app I get the following error when MSAL tries to authenticate.

`window.crypto.randomUUID is not a function`

I've seen [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/cryptography/5.0/cryptography-apis-not-supported-on-blazor-webassembly) article on microsoft's website, not sure if it is related or not, but I wouldn't have expected MS to use it in .NET 7 if it was removed.

I can't work out what to do about this, can anyone help?

What I've tried so far

1. Putting this into my client csproj file

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <TrimmerRootAssembly Include="Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal" />
</ItemGroup>
```

2. Putting this into my client csproj file

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <BlazorLinkerDescriptor Include="LinkerConfig.xml" />
</ItemGroup>
```

with this in the xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<linker>
  <assembly fullname="Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal" />
</linker>
```

Comment: Sounds very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73541196/548997). Perhaps adding that exclusion to your project file will resolve this deployment issue as well?

Comment: @Lex Updated my question to mention that I've tried that, thank you! Unfortunately, it didn't work :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was that window.crypto.randomUUID only runs when your domain is localhost, or when the request is via HTTPS.

Solution: Instead of http (which seems to be VS default after publishing) use https.