# How to fix Uncaught TypeError: window.crypto.randomUUID is not a function in a React JS app using MSAL after deploying it in IIS

Tags: reactjs, authentication, azure-ad-msal

I've encountered an issue with my React JS application that uses the MSAL (Microsoft Authentication Library) for Single Sign-On (SSO) after deploying it to IIS. The application works perfectly fine in my local development environment, but when I deploy it to IIS, I get the following error in the browser console:

```
index.54ff3299.js:899 Authentication error: TypeError: window.crypto.randomUUID is not a function
    at di (index.54ff3299.js:899:22460)
    at zf.getRequestCorrelationId (index.54ff3299.js:899:145330)
    at zf.loginPopup (index.54ff3299.js:899:145548)
    at Ty.loginPopup (index.54ff3299.js:899:151621)
    at c (index.54ff3299.js:899:154359)
    at Object.Sk (index.54ff3299.js:29:9871)
    at Ck (index.54ff3299.js:29:10025)
    at Ek (index.54ff3299.js:29:10082)
    at o0 (index.54ff3299.js:29:31522)
    at fb (index.54ff3299.js:29:31939)
```

It seems to be related to the window.crypto.randomUUID function, which is not recognized in the deployed environment.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue with MSAL and React after deploying to IIS? What might be causing this problem, and how can I fix it? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[The problem was that window.crypto.randomUUID only runs when your domain is localhost, or when the request is via HTTPS.

Solution: Instead of http (which seems to be VS default after publishing) use https.] - Peter Morris

I found this answer in a similar question asked.

[Blazor WASM error: 'window.crypto.randomUUID is not a function'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75757428/blazor-wasm-error-window-crypto-randomuuid-is-not-a-function)